# directly accessing area through url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-5, area

I'm developing an application using MVC 5. I have added a new area which contains a view called **Register** and gradually adding content to it. For debugging purposes, I'm trying to access that area directly through url after logging in to application. I'm using the url: http://localhost:port/Area/Account/Manage/Register

But I'm getting error. How will be the url, If need to view **Register** page directly. Please find the directory structure below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the view file directly. You should access it via an action method.

Create an action method called `Register` in your `ManageController` (if not exists) and return the view

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
  return View();
}
```

now you can access this by navigating to `yoursitename/account/manage/register` assuming you haven't altered the default route registration for the area.